# Java Collection#clear reclaim memory

Tags: java, performance, memory

With the following function:
[Collection#clear](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#clear%28%29)

how can I attempt to reclaim memory that could be freed from an invocation?   Code sample:

```
public class Foo
{
    private static Collection<Bar> bars;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        bars = new ArrayList<Bar>();  
        for(int i = 0; i < 100000;i++)
        {  
            bars.add(new Bar());
        }      
         bars.clear();  
         //how to get memory back here
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

What I am looking for is similar to how ArrayList.remove reclaims memory by copying the new smaller array.

Answer (score 3):

It is more efficient to only reclaim memory when you need to.  In this case it is much simpler/faster to let the GC do it asynchronous when there is a need to do.  You can give the JVM a hint using `System.gc()` but this is likely to be slower and complicate your program.

> how ArrayList.remove reclaims memory by copying the new smaller array.

It doesn't do this. It never shrinks the array, nor would you need to.

If you really need to make the collection smaller, which I seriously doubt, you can create a new ArrayList which has a copy of the elements you want to keep.

Answer (score 2):

```
bars= null ;
```

would be the best.  `clear` doesn't guarantee to release any memory, only to reset the logical contents to "empty".

In fact, `bars= null ;` doesn't guarantee that memory will be immediately released.  However, it would make the object previously pointed by `bars` and all its dependents "ready for garbage collection" ("finalization", really, but let's keep this simple).  If the JVM finds itself needing memory, it will collect these objects (other simplification here:  this depends on the exact garbage collection algorithm the JVM is configured to use).

Comment: Of course it does.  You just said it in your own answer.  Nobody is saying that memory will be actually collected, but for all practical effects it is in a available state.  It's like a barman.  You have glasses in a shelf and you have glasses drying in the sink.  How many do you have available?  It's a matter of degree.  If you started running out of glasses (memory), you would quickly and with little effort resort to the ones in by the sink.  So, they were "available".

Comment: You are speaking from the point of view of the person who washes the glasses.  I'm speaking from the point of view of the bartender.

Comment: You're right; it wasn't clear whether you were referring to the array or the old instances

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

At some point after there are no more references to the objects, the GC will collect them for you.

**EDIT**: To force the ArrayList to release its reference to the giant empty array, call [`trimToSize()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#trimToSize%28%29)

Comment: so i cant resize the collection?

Comment: similar to how arraylist does, as an analog.

Comment: @Woot4Moo: See `trimToSize()`.  Note that it will not trigger GC, and that `.remove()` does not do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't *force* memory reclamation, that will happen when garbage collection occurs.

If you use `clear()` you will clear the *references* to objects that were contained in the collection.   If there are no other references to those objects, then they will be reclaimed next time GC is run.

The collection itself (which just contains references, not the objects referred to), will not be resized.  The only way to get back the storage used by the collection is to set the reference `bars` to `null` so it will eventually be reclaimed.